# Getting array key while using in_array

Tags: php, arrays

This is the array;

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
```

When I use "in_array" for "Irix" it returns 'true'

The question is, how can get Irix's array key value (2)?

Comment: [`array_search( 'Irix', $os )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: damn! i was looking for php classes for that
thank you Juhana